# Can the vote count fetch error pop-up for deleted post be more explanatory?

Tags: feature-request, vote-count, error-message, deleted-posts

I tried viewing vote count about 5 times on an answer and I kept getting an error pop-up

[image]

I was actually wondering why an error was occuring because my internet connection was ok and there was nothing that could be causing the error. Until I tried to vote on the answer and got this

[image]

I now understood why an error was occuring during vote count fetch. My proposal is that the error dialog for vote count fetch on deleted post be more explanatory. For example

> This post has been deleted; you don't have the privilege to view vote count on deleted posts

This would help save time I wasted continuing to try to view the vote count.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, changed to feature request.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh yeah. Thanks!!!