# What is the purpose of a Bounty on a feature-request

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

Are StackExchange employees motivated by reputation gain ?
Even though a bounty is made to attract attention to a post, the final goal is to reward the best answer with an amount of reputation.

Then what is the point of a Bounty on a feature request that can either be Completed or Declined by an employee that will specify it in the answer section and get the bounty.

E.g : [Can the vote count fetch error pop-up for deleted post be more explanatory?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209751/can-the-vote-count-fetch-error-pop-up-for-deleted-post-be-more-explanatory)

Comment: Also related, potential duplicate (which has a staff response): [What's the intention of setting a bounty on a \[feature-request\] or a \[bug\]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300822/whats-the-intention-of-setting-a-bounty-on-a-feature-request-or-a-bug). Also: [Does awarding bounties to a feature-request actually work (i.e. change prioritization)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211156/does-awarding-bounties-to-a-feature-request-actually-work-i-e-change-prioritiz)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point is to gain attention and upvotes.

A heavily upvoted question is more likely to be implemented.

Comment: Makes sense.. Just thought it was weird in a way because regular users won't post in those posts. But they will upvote it indeed

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd You can see reason for the bounty `This question has not received enough attention`

Comment: I got here just now after searching for this precise question. While I can see that this is indeed the supposed reason, I will also say that at leas for me it is not working at all, since here on meta I am just ignoring most bounties just because of the points @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd made.

Answer (score 1):

The point of bounty is simply to attract attention to a question to gain more comments, ideas, answers, and votes.
Which is just as useful with feature requests.

This allows the community and staff to get an idea of what people think, whether it's a good idea or not etc.

> Then what is the point of a Bounty on a feature request that can either be Completed or Declined by an employee that will specify it in the answer section and get the bounty.

So what if staff/mods get some rep for fixing a bug or implementing a feature request.
You can argue their answer is not a valid answer as it's just a note to state *job done*, and so bounty and upvote rep gained from their "answer" is not as per the normal play and rules.

However, you can also argue, that an answer from staff/mod stating "I've implemented that feature you and other users have requested (by their upvotes)" surely deserved a return thank you by their gaining some rep?

As while their rep gained is not from a great answer to a question their actions were still helping the community, just as a good answer to a valid question helps the community .

Let's face it, a feature request isn't really a question that requires a great answer anyway, as we're on MSO...