# What's the intention of setting a bounty on a [feature-request] or a [bug]?

Tags: discussion, bounties, meta

I'm curious why people set bounties on [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s. AFAIK it won't speed up the implementation or fixing progress of the FR/B, because the coders in SE don't matter about them very much. So why is there bounties? What's the possible intention of the setter?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128818/bounties-on-meta-to-attract-stack-exchange-employee-attention (you might even call it a dupe, but it's 5 1/2 years old)

Comment: related article that laid down the way how things work over here: [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/). Worth noting that the second part ("Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do") seems to be followed almost religiously

Comment: Related: [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: Also related, potential duplicate (though this question's better solely by virtue of having a staff response): [What is the purpose of a Bounty on a feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210501/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-bounty-on-a-feature-request)

Answer (score 9):

Yagmoth [is correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300823/50049), it's one way to draw attention to something. However, there are two goals one might be looking to accomplish by doing so:

- Get more feedback from the community on a particular [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request),
- Get some kind of official response on a particular [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or perhaps [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

You also might want to accomplish both. If all you're after is *community* input, then the bounty is probably your best bet. If what you really want is an official response from *us* (SO/SE) then it's probably better to [just use the contact form instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact). This saves you a bit of rep and ensures a paper trail gets created while the right people get pinged.

I can't promise that we'll always be prepared to write an answer to something immediately, but we generally can and will leave a comment to let folks know it hasn't eluded us, and we'll answer as soon as we're able.

In any event, you're welcome to leave a bounty for any reason that you wish - just know that it isn't mandatory in order to make sure we see something that might have fallen through the cracks.

Comment: Additional upvotes often go to questions with bounties which in themselves should help to determine priorities when deciding what to fix/include next.  Perhaps by feedback you already mean additional answers, comments, edits and votes.

Comment: Using the contact form feels like a bet. Once placed, you have no idea if it worked or not. There is no way to know if your request has been submitted, and sometimes it take weeks to get a response (talking from personal experience). In case of bugs I'm sorry but it's just too long, and better leave something with a visible trail. (e.g. bounty where you know for sure "it worked, it's here, and it might actually do something".)

Answer (score 7):

It serve as a poke, to draw attention to it (the bug or feature-request)

It happen as the backlog is really big and some old requests are more than some years old.

As no need to write a question if a duplicate already exist, but if you found a bug today and your duplicate is 3 year old its discouraging, so the bounty allow to draw some attention.