# How to give a chance to my cheesy riddle?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, 10th-anniversary

I submitted a poor answer on the competition *[Who Cut the Cheese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese)*? Then, I put a lot of effort into making an [online cheesy riddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316605/275467), but I couldn't create a new post, so I edited the bad, negative-scored post. Unluckily, I feel that it has become a victim of starvation, and as a result, users don't really see it.

I went ahead and asked the riddle [experts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74434/whats-wrong-with-this-cheesy-riddle), and now I have edited my riddle again. I want to give this cheesy riddle a chance. How do I do this?

In other words, what can I do to make people see my riddle?

---

Edit: I see a -1, if this is off-topic, let me know, and I'll delete it. I posted here, because I was told by a ninja to do so :)

Comment: Not sure what you ask (sorry, not fan of riddles especially when it's about bugs), if you mean you can't post new answer there change this into bug report and explain plainly what you get when clicking the "Answer This Question" button. The question is not locked yet, and anyone should be able to post more than one answer.

Comment: No @ShadowWizard, I mean how to "bump my post" or something, that people can see it now, so the riddle has a chance to be appreciated by people! Because, since it was edited in place of the bad post, it remained hidden in the dark... It was/is protected, so when I made the riddle I didn't have enough rep to post a new one. Now posting a new one, would result in a duplicate post. :/ Maybe I should edit that info to my question?

Comment: The post is in the positive, and so is the question.  It gets bumped to the top of Home whenever someone edits it, and the modified link when you edit yours will take them straight to yours.  Making excessive edits in an attempt to get more eyes on it is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Just edit again (with valid edit, not "BUMP! Edited!!") and it will bump the whole question with direct link to your answer for those who check what changed. Other than that, no way.

Comment: As for -1 it's not due to off topic but, I think, due to people frowning about you ranting about not getting attention. :)

Comment: The cheese post is no longer featured, and it's gotten well over 60 responses. People are probably just sick of reloading that post. It may not be easy or possible to get a lot of attention at this point... actually, this very question about how to get attention might be the best you can do.

Comment: @SOLO or worst, meta effect goes both ways. Usually not good for OP.

Comment: ShadowWizard oops :) Maybe I should delete it. That edit thing works... @SOLO yeah but it doesn't succeed in making you check my riddle :P

Comment: [Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/275467/gsamaras?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) are supposed to improve posts and make them easier to read, in order to help the OP and help readers understand their questions better. [Your numerous edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/275467/gsamaras?tab=activity&sort=revisions) on the Who Cut the Cheese thread seem a thinly veiled attempt to bump the question so as to draw attention to your answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I see your point. Most edits where to edit the code, since some people were actually reading it! How's, you are right, I got a bit dragged off. Lesson learned, thanks! Sharing it on FB seems to helped a lot!

Comment: Wow, someone who doesn't immediately respond on the defensive. That's a rarity on SE. Good for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> As a result, I feel that it became a victim of starvation, and people didn't really see it.

That's not because your post was at -1 (according to the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/316605/timeline)). I doubt it would have gained more attention when you would have posted it immediately in its current form. You were only the 37<sup>th</sup> user to post an answer and just simply 'late to the party'.

The problem with these kind of posts is that the first few answers (the [Fastest Guns In The West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/295232)) will get many (up)votes in a very short time, especially when the post is [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). We can't really blame later visitors that they're fed up after reading (and upvoting) the first 5-6 answers, and do not pay attention to later ones. This is the same feedback loop we see on e.g. [Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317418/295232), and it also happens on more serious Meta posts (just check [my 2 highest scoring answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=answers&sort=votes)).

> In other words, what to do to make people see my riddle?

You really don't have much options than posting direct links to it, e.g. on your profile or on social media. Be aware that posting questions like this (especially if you do it multiple times) could be seen as a cry for attention, or worse, as spam.

Comment: I agree, thanks. Do you think that I should delete this question, since it might already seem like this, thus the -1. I mean I would have done it, but I feel guilty having you posting an answer, and all the commentators, and then delete it, without accepting your good answer...

Comment: It can be a useful question, since most of the answers to 'how do I get more attention' questions (post a bounty, update with progress about your own research) do not apply here.

Comment: OK, convinced! However, I am sure that if I had post the riddle from the start (and not the bad post), it would be better, I mean it wouldn't receive a downvote I believe, what do you think? Didn't you enjoy the riddle even a little? :) In any case, a good lesson was learned: As my father says (translated from Greek): Dip your tongue into your mind, before you talk!

Comment: I actually ignored that entire Q&A, since I dislike cheese. (Rather strange for a Dutch guy, I know...)

Comment: Feta is much different than your "heavy", my taste says, cheese. And my riddle is all about that, but as you wish, thanks again, cheers!

Comment: Having looked at it, I couldn't see that it was a riddle. I actually ended up downvoting it as it didn't entertain at all - I couldn't understand where any riddle was supposed to be, and in fact clicked on things until I tried the min value you stated and it came up with the message. Not sure what the expected point was supposed to be - sorry.